# Что означает var sum=0 (в js)?

Tags: javascript

```
var sum = 0;

while (true) {

  var value = +prompt("Введите число", '');

  if (!value) break; // (*)

  sum += value;

}
alert( 'Сумма: ' + sum );
```

**Непонятно использование var sum=0**, т.е. sum+= value. 

__
(Чтобы разобраться в коде, менял в алерт сум на вэлью, выдаёт 0...)

Comment: А что тут непонятного? Инициализируется переменная для суммы. Затем в цикле выводится окно, в которое предлагается ввести число, введённое число прибавляется к сумме. Если введена пустая строка, то происходит выход из цикла и выводится окно с суммой.

Comment: @Byulent - почему не ответ?

Comment: @Igor сейчас будет.

Answer (score 3):

А что тут непонятного? Инициализируется переменная для суммы. Затем в цикле выводится окно, в которое предлагается ввести число, введённое число прибавляется к сумме. Если введена пустая строка или 0, то происходит выход из цикла и выводится окно с суммой.

Унарный плюс, я так понимаю, нужен для преобразования строки в число.

Comment: Добавьте к "пустая строка или 0". И да, вы правильно понимаете :)

Comment: Зачем сум+= ? Спасибо. (Которое означает сум=0+вэлью+вэлью+...)

Comment: @ОлегОстапчук Затем, что к переменной глобальной области видимости (`sum`) прибавляется переменная с введённым значением (`value`). Введённое значение сохраняется в отдельную переменную, потому что оно также используется для проверки продолжения выполнения цикла. А `+=` -  это сумма с присваиванием.